# Case insensitive document ID matching in Couchbase

Tags: java, database, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I'm using `com.couchbase.client` maven dependency in java spring project. I fetch a couchbase document from code in following way:

```
JsonDocument document = bucket.get(id); //matches id case sensitively
```

But i've got a new requirement. I have to fetch the documents based on case insensitive matching of **id**.

For example:
Let's say couchbase has a document with id `heLLo_Doc`

When i execute `bucket.get("hello_doc")` i want the document with id `heLLo_Doc` to be returned. If there are more than one document with same lowercase id(ex: `Hello_Doc`,`hEllo_doc` etc) i need to get all those documents.

Is there any method provided by couchbase to do this?

The worst way to do this is to search for all possibilities, that i don't want to do.

Answer (score 3):

There is not such a feature if you just want to use the KV engine. But, you can still add a lowercase version of your id into your document and search it via n1ql with "LOWER" https://docs.couchbase.com/server/5.5/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/stringfun.html#fn-str-lower.

if you need to bring variations of your ID, like 'HelloDoc', you also can use Full-Text search with some fuzziness level:
https://blog.couchbase.com/fuzzy-matching/

Comment: I can use n1ql with "LOWER" but what if the document id has upper case letters in couchbase. And also can you explain what is a KV engine?

Comment: You will need to also store it with lower or  apply it during the comparison, like "lower(myId) = lower(Hello_Doc) ". About the key-value store checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26527466/what-is-the-key-value-storage-in-couch-base

Answer (score 3):

If you want use N1QL. You need to create functional index on document key

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON default(LOWER(META().id));
SELECT * FROM default WHERE LOWER(META().id) = "hello_doc";
```

OR

```
SELECT META().id FROM default WHERE LOWER(META().id) = "hello_doc";
The second query gives actual document keys then you can pass this to your existing bucket.get() call too.
```

Comment: This will work. Thanks @[vsr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6080536/vsr).
Doesn't couchbase SDK provides a method for this kind of id matching? (this will help if i don't want to use N1QL queries)